# How to replicate "Look Up" functionality in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uikit

iOS 10 replaced the "Define" action you could initiate from any text selection (which I believe used [`UIReferenceLibraryViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller?language=objc)) with "Look Up" (see [iMore article](https://www.imore.com/look-replaces-define-ios-10-heres-how-use-it)). I want to be able to invoke the same functionality in my app from custom UI, the same way I can from UIReferenceLibraryViewController. Is that possible? Is there an API for this?

Comment: No. See https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/301-the-dictionary-hiding-inside-uikit which makes the same complaint. File an enhancement request.

Comment: @matt care to make this an answer?

Comment: @matt I suspected the answer was no, but I wouldn't have been shocked if there was an API hiding somewhere that I didn't find in Googling before posting this. Yes, I'm complaining a bit, but I was also honestly asking a question.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Especially when right now, for some reason, UIReferenceLibraryViewController's dictionary function is incredible slow:(